# How can I reproject a layer in a spatialite database

Tags: coordinate-system, spatialite

I'm writing an android mobile application and, for performance reasons, I want to reproject my layers to match the basemap's projection.

Is there a command to do that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a function to reproject geometry:

```
ST_Transform( geom Geometry , newSRID Integer ) : Geometry
```

List of functions can be found [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html).

Note that in case you would want to rewrite existing geometry in Geometry column with reprojected data (instead of creating new table), you will need to update `geometry_columns` table and enter new SRID (in `srid` attribute) for the table with reprojected column there.

Comment: Updating in place will not succeed without dropping some triggers first. Easier is to create a new table, drop the old and vacuum. Remember to create spatial and attribute indexes and check carefully that your requests really utilize the spatial index. It is somehow tricky in Spatialite. And the up-to-date list of SQL functions is here http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.